# Disable Delete for 1 Cell in UITableView

Tags: objective-c, c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have a UITableView. It pulls information from the address book where needed. I also have the bottom cell programatically made to be a button that loads up the address book.

My problem is when I allow the user to delete a row by swiping right, it shows it for the last cell I have made as a button. Is there a way to not allow a delete function showing on just 1 cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:` in the table view's `dataSource` and return `NO` for the row you don't want to be deletable.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement `[UITableViewDelegate tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:]` and return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` only for the cells that can be deleted. Return `UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone` for the cells that can't be deleted.